# Wi-Fi only connects when router set to TKIP, but won't use AES

Tags: security, wireless, networking, kubuntu-netbook

For some reason, my computer (running Kubuntu netbook edition now, previously UNR) won't connect to my router when it's set to AES+TKIP.
As soon as I switch the router to TKIP only, the computer connects.

1. Should I be concerned about this? Doesn't TKIP bring me back down to the ultimately flawed WPA?
2. If so, is there a way to get [K]ubuntu to use AES?

EDIT: this is the 10.04 release version of Kubuntu Netbook

Hardware: Asus EeePC 1000H (WiFi chipset: RALINK RT2860)

Comment: Is this Lucid 10.04 (stable) or Maverick 10.10 (testing)?

Comment: @fluteflute: I added version info.

Comment: Are you sure your hardware supports AES?

Comment: I would suggest you report a bug on launchpad by running the command `ubuntu-bug network-manager-kde`

Comment: @Dennis of course I'm not sure :) Didn't realise that could be an issue. But I would think relatively modern hardware, like the Asus eeePC 1000H would work, no?

Comment: I added the hardware information to the post as it's very pertinent to the whole question (especially when it comes to feature support).

Answer (score 4):

This has everything to do with the RALINK RT2860 chipset (or more its driver) that's embedded in your Asus EeePC 1000H. [This thread details upgrading the driver](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1476007). This might seem a little extreme but from what I've seen of the RT2860, you either upgrade or forget about AES.

There are a few formatting issues, problems with files, etc with that post, so I'm rewriting it here.

1. Head to http://www.ralinktech.com, hover over `software`, click `linux` and look for `RT2860` (current string is `RT2860PCI/mPCI/CB/PCIe(RT2760/RT2790/RT2860/RT2890)`, version 2.4.0.0)
2. Download it and extract it. I had problems extracting it in Gnome. I had to rename it from `.tar.bz2` to `.tar.gz`.
3. Open a terminal window, `cd` into the extracted directory.
4. Edit `os/linux/config.mk` and change options `HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT` and `HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT` to `=y`
5. Edit `common/cmm_wpa.c` (gedit will throw an encoding error - select Western and click retry). Search for `MIX_CIPHER_NOTUSE` and replace the entire line with this:

   ```
   WPA_MIX_PAIR_CIPHER FlexibleCipher = WPA_TKIPAES_WPA2_TKIPAES;
   ```
6. It's finally time to compile and install! Yey!

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   sudo make
   sudo make install
   sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
   sudo rmmod rt2860sta
   ```
7. We need to move the old driver out the way. We probably shouldn't delete it in case we need it again so:

   ```
   sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/staging/rt2860/rt2860sta.ko rt2860sta.ko.dist
   ```

   If you're using a 64bit installation, you might need to change `/lib/` to `/lib64/`
8. Now we just need to move in the new driver and load it.

   ```
   sudo cp os/linux/rt2860sta.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/staging/rt2860/
   ```

   `/lib64/...` for 64bit installs, again.

   ```
   sudo depmod -a
   sudo modprobe rt2860sta
   ```

   Everything should burst into life. If it doesn't you may need to run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`
9. For persistence run `sudoedit /etc/modules` and add `rt2860sta` as a new line at the end. This will make sure the driver gets loaded at boot.

If it all goes to pot and the new driver doesn't work, just remove the version you copied in and remove the `.dist` off the old version we renamed.

**Note**: If you change kernel a lot, you want to invest in some DKMS script to do all this. There may even be deb packages for this driver.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved in Maverick. I just upgraded and it actually works better than before.